# JBoss AMQ 7.0.1 Management Console wiki page throws exception javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : io.fabric8:type=Fabric

Tags: jboss-amq

I have installed Jboss AMQ 7.0.1.
Everything working fine. But getting following exception if I try to browse Wiki in Web Management Console.

> javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : io.fabric8:type=Fabric

Stack trace:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: io.fabric8:type=Fabric
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1375)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:920)
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.extractMBeanParameterInfos(ExecHandler.java:167)
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.extractOperationTypes(ExecHandler.java:143)
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:84)
at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:40)
at org.jolokia.handler.JsonRequestHandler.handleRequest(JsonRequestHandler.java:89)
at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerExecutorLocal.handleRequest(MBeanServerExecutorLocal.java:109)
at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerHandler.dispatchRequest(MBeanServerHandler.java:159)
at org.jolokia.backend.LocalRequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(LocalRequestDispatcher.java:99)
at org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.callRequestDispatcher(BackendManager.java:413)
at org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.handleRequest(BackendManager.java:158)
at org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.executeRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:197)
at org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.handleGetRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:86)
at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet$4.handleRequest(AgentServlet.java:430)
at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.handleSecurely(AgentServlet.java:301)
at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.handle(AgentServlet.java:277)
at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.doGet(AgentServlet.java:237)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter$3.run(AuthenticationFilter.java:201)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter.executeAs(AuthenticationFilter.java:198)
at io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at io.hawt.web.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at io.hawt.web.XXSSProtectionFilter.doFilter(XXSSProtectionFilter.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at io.hawt.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.process(SessionExpiryFilter.java:148)
at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(SessionExpiryFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecutingExecutionStrategy.invoke(ExecutingExecutionStrategy.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:133)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After some search I found it may be a reason of Fabric up-gradation, but not sure what exactly, I have to do to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge all the wiki functionality in the Hawtio-based web console has been disabled in Red Hat JBoss AMQ so I think this can safely be ignored.

Comment: Oh, that is the reason. Thanks. It would be better if that is mentioned in AMQ console guide. That is official and easy to make understand people.